# Laptop unilaterally restarting

Tags: windows-10, laptop, power-management, asus-laptop

My Windows is configured so that when I close the lid of the laptop, it goes into "Sleep" mode (whether plugged in or not).

But almost every time I close the lid, I reopen it to find that Windows has restarted, and I've lost everything that I had open in my previous session.

There must be a secret switch somewhere so that I can preserve my desktop when I close the lid of my laptop. What is it?

**UPDATE:** apparently it's not just when I close the lid. Last night I left my computer on with the lid open (and plugged in); this morning I restarted and found that the computer had summarily rebooted. And it's not Windows updates, either; my Windows updates are configured to install only when I say so, and there were no new updates this morning. And there's nothing in the Windows event logs, except a big gap between about 1:27 am and when I turned on this morning.

Comment: Do any files exist in C:\Windows\Minidump (or does C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP exist) from recent?

Comment: @JustinKrejcha Yes! What do I do with that file?

Comment: It appears that the issue is related to a BSOD (by default it's set to automatically restart after one). If you upload it to a file sharing service like Dropbox and then give a link, I may be able to figure out exactly what is causing it.

Comment: @JustinKrejcha https://1drv.ms/f/s!AswBr0durGuImDwnuphdfoEEATX_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Windows may have crashed. By default, Windows is set to automatically restart once this happens.

The error is:

> KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
>
> STOP: 0x00000139 (0x0000000000000003, 0xffffbc01397364f0, 0xffffbc0139736448, 
>   0x0000000000000000))

Unfortunately, because this is a crash started not by a specific driver, but by Windows itself, **it is not immediately clear where the problem is** (a slightly deeper analysis can be performed).

For now, you can try some troubleshooting steps [as recommended by Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check---bug-check-0x139-kernel-security-check-failure):

> - If you recently added hardware to the system, try removing or replacing it. Or check with the manufacturer to see if any patches are available.
> - If new device drivers or system services have been added recently, try removing or updating them. Try to determine what changed in the system that caused the new bug check code to appear.
> - Check the System Log in Event Viewer for additional error messages that might help pinpoint the device or driver that is causing the error. Look for critical errors in the system log that occurred in the same time window as the blue screen.
> - Look in **Device Manager** to see if any devices are marked with the exclamation point (!). Review the events log displayed in driver properties for any faulting driver. Try updating the related driver.
> - Run a virus detection program. Viruses can infect all types of hard disks formatted for Windows, and resulting disk corruption can generate system bug check codes. Make sure the virus detection program checks the Master Boot Record for infections.

---

As a side note, it appears that the technical reason is due to corruption of a [LIST_ENTRY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It appears that it is identifiable usually with some detective work. I'll attempt to update this answer when I can once I've done this.

Answer (score 1):

*Sleep* keeps the processor running, albeit slowly, so that it drains the battery. If you leave the laptop in *Sleep* too long, the battery drains to a critical level and the system simply shuts down, losing your work, **unless Hibernate is enabled** and allowed to save the current state to SSD or HDD.

You might wish to use *Hibernate* as the default on closing the lid. With a SSD, it's almost as fast to resume from *Hibernate* as from *Sleep*.

Comment: Alas, this did not solve it. See the update to my question.